# using 2 css class for click function doesn't work in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-selectors

I have to following code snippet. My understanding is that, the following code fires, when `<li class="topics">Topics</li>` is clicked on. However, what I am observing is that, the click function doesn't fire.

```
   $(".li .topics").click(function () {

   }
```

However, if I am removing the `.li` ,

```
   $(".topics").click(function () {

   }
```

Then the click function works fine, anything I am doing wrong here? Please advise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`li` is not a class, it is an element. what you can do is remove the period from the `.li` and have something like this:

```
$("li.topics").click(function () {}
```

Also, when you have a space between the classes, it looks for the second class to be nested inside of the first, however, when you remove the space, it looks for that element which has that class.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a class "li" then this should also work

```
$(".li, .topics").click(function(){
   alert("clicked");    
});​
```